# How to Cut a ImageView to a subimage in the range of four specified points

Tags: android, android-widget

I know we can cat a imageView by useing system action "com.android.camera.action.CROP"

But  some times i want to cut the image by myself like:

bitmap of imageView A is 300dip*300dip ;

sub-image should be the range in the four point lefttop(0,0) leftbottom(0,100) rightbottom(100,100),righttop(100,0).

How to create the sub-image(bitmap)?

Answer (score 11):

use this static method:

```
Bitmap cropedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(source, x, y, width, height);
```

source - the original bitmap

x - The x coordinate of the first pixel in source

y - The y coordinate of the first pixel in source